# discord.py как убрать принт ошибки NSFW

Tags: python, discord.py

хотел сделать команду и ошибку для NSFW (вывод ошибки в чат), но при проверки ошибки, в консоли еще показывается ошибка disnake.ext.commands.errors.NSFWChannelRequired:
как можно убрать её но при этом оставить вывод ошибки в чат?
вот код:

```
class Nsfw(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_command_error(self, ctx, error):
        if isinstance(error, commands.errors.NSFWChannelRequired):
            embed=disnake.Embed(title = "Этот канал не NSFW", description = f"Этот канал не имеет отметку NSFW!")
            return await ctx.send(embed=embed)
            
    @commands.command()
    @commands.is_nsfw()
    async def hello(self, ctx):
        ctx.send("mmmmm")
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте - `if isinstance(error, commands.NSFWChannelRequired)`

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: не помогло, ошибка в консоли всё равно показывается